# How can I use marquee package conditionally in Futter?

Tags: flutter, dart, marquee

In the image you see that some texts take more space than the width provided by their parent widget. I want to use marquee so that when the text is longer than the width, it scrolls. But, it should not always be scrollable, only when it is longer, not even when the text is fitted inside the parent widget. How can I use marquee only when the text is long?
[image: the image]

Comment: You need to check in length of string like string.length > 25 ? Marquee() : Text()

Comment: @RaviLimbani That is a hack at best. That will work on the exact device you have in front of you and be horribly wrong on most other devices.

Comment: @RaviLimbani Yes. You are right. But what is the solution?

Comment: Is there any way I can split the text to the second line when it overflows?

Comment: @MortezaEhsani I think this solution i can't find another solution. You need to set condition on basis of screen width like width > 250 then string.length > 25

Comment: You mean there is no other way to split the text??

Comment: I don't know if any way available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Use marquee only if text is long]

```dart
bool _willTextOverflow({required String text, required TextStyle style}) {
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style),
      maxLines: 1,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: maxWidth);

    return textPainter.didExceedMaxLines;
  }
```

Read more about this [here](https://twitter.com/rohantaneja_/status/1479499425387003910).

Get the entire code [here](https://gist.github.com/rohan20/ab7b2d9650dc68f228f1b548dd383a37).